# How can Durbin-Watson and SPEC give Opposite Results?

Tags: regression, autocorrelation

I am modelling house prices against sales amount using a simple linear regression model.

My SPEC (Option in SAS) says IID (p-value > 0.05) but my DW (Option in SAS) says a strong 1st order autocorrelation (DW<2). How can this happen?
I have included the result screenshot[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Durbin Watson test it's not applicable in small sample sizes. If your data set has more than p*10 (number of independent variables * 10) observations then you can consider it large. If your data set has less than p*5 observations than you can consider it small. In a case of small sample, DW test cannot be applied and in such a situation bootstrap procedure may be a solution to this problem.

Also you can check the table of Critical Values of the Durbin-Watson Statistic to see if they are correlated or not, because DW ~2 it's a rule of thumb, also DW ~1.6 value are used often.